# How to trigger supervisor exitcode with a php exception code

Tags: php, exception, supervisord, exit-code, error-code

I use supervisord for managing a long-running PHP CLI process (a job-queue worker). Under certain conditions I need to prevent supervisor from restarting the process, I do this by adding a line like the following to my supervisord config:

> `exitcodes=99,255`

and trigger it from php using:

> `exit(99);`

But I would like to use an `Exception` for this purpose, so that my code is more object-oriented. I tried to use a `RuntimeException` and an `ErrorException` but neither helped.

Any suggestions? Thanks